Global Style defined in the "App.xaml" didn't work after imported the prism framework
I'm trying a WPF demo with Prism Framework. I have create a new WPF project and imported Prism.DryIOC package, then modified the App.xaml file shown here. In the file, I have defined a global style for all button elements to set the background.
<Application
    x:Class="DemoTest.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DemoTest"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="BurlyWood" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

Then in the MainView.xaml, I created a new button:
<Window x:Class="DemoTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DemoTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Height="30"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>

The problem is when I run or debug the program, the background color is the default color, not the color I had defined in the style of the App.xaml. It seems that the style defined in the app.xaml does not work.
I have tried to defined the style with a key like this:
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="btnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="BurlyWood" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

and used the style with the key:
<Button Height="30" Style="{StaticResource btn btnStyle}" />

but it throws an exception :

Exception: Unable to find resource named 'btn btnStyle'. Resource names are case sensitive.

It also doesn't work when the style is directly defined in the <Application.Resources>.
And when I created another project which does not use the Prism framework, it worked correctly. So it seems that this issue is related to the Prism framework?

There is a erro in  quote the sytle by key , the key name was wrong. I corrected it when running the program, it aslo throw the Exception.

Have you tried <Button Height="30" Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}" />?

yes, I have tried,but it throw the Excption:
Exception: Unable to find resource named 'btnStyle'. Resource names are case sensitive.@h.m.i.13
